# Extract date from a string

Tags: java, regex

I would like to find date from java string.But i can not able to do this please help

```
String : 01-02-2014 <2>
Ineed output like :01-02-2014
```

My code:

```
public String rejex(String idate){
 String result = null;
 try{
    String regex = "([1-9]|[012][0-9]|3[01])[-/]\\s*(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/]\\s*((19|20)?[0-9]{2})";
    result = idate.replaceAll(regex, "$1-$2-$3");
 }catch(Exception e){}
    return result;

     }
```

Comment: You just want to remove everything apart from `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Comment: yes remove everything except dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: you are not just extracting, do you want to validate the date as well?

Comment: Yes i want to validate date

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing what you are after (the date segments) with themselves.

If you want to extract it, this will work:

```
    String regex = "(([1-9]|[012][0-9]|3[01])[-/]\\s*(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/]\\s*((19|20)?[0-9]{2})).*?<(\\d+)>";
    String str = "This is a random string 01-02-2014 <123> this is another part of that random string";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println("Date: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Number: " + m.group(6));
    }
```

Yields:

```
Date: 01-02-2014
Number: 123
```

Comment: What to do to get 2 inside <>

Answer (score 0):

just extract `\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d{4}` out, let `SimpleDateFormat` do the parsing job.

Comment: can i have  regex code for this one

Comment: it's very hard to decide if the extracted string is a valid date with regex. E.g. `29-02-2000 (valid)` and `29-02-2013 (invalid)` the `\\d\\d....` in my answer is regex to extract the "date string". but you need check if it is a valid date by SimpleDateFormat. @user2601972

Answer (score 0):

if space is there all the time then it's simple.

```
 String dateStr = "01-02-2014 <2>"
 String dateSplit[] = dateStr.split(" ");
 //dateSplit[0] is what u are looking for
```

or

```
 String dateStr = "01-02-2014 <2>"
 String dateSplit[] = dateStr.split("<");
 //dateSplit[0].trim() is what u are looking for
```

and then simply use SimpleDateFormat to converting it into Date.